# WCF ChannelFactory against SOA principles?

Tags: wcf, soa, channelfactory

Is sharing a project containing the wcf interface and datacontracts and using these via ChannelFactory to consume the service against SOA principles?

My architect is advising that generating a proxy using Add Service Reference is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that depends on a some things: your infrastructure, security policies, governance, etc.

We design our WSDLs (service and message contracts) and XML Schemas (data contracts) and then use svcutil.exe* to generate a proxy.  At that point, we have code we can either use to consume or stand up a service.  Of course, I am just talking about the code, the output.config will be modified with proper behaviors, bindings and endpoints as those are decided.

Once the service is stood up, it's fronted by an XML gateway.  At which point we can begin testing the services using the 'Add Service Reference...'.  If you're just looking to save some time and hand someone else your pre-generated proxy or your WSDLs aren't exposed (as they're behind an XML gateway that does not echo them), then what you're doing seems fine.

Otherwise, I'd expect consumers to be able to 'Add Service Reference...' and generate their own clients.

*Java-based applications use something else (WSDL2Java/ClientGen/built-in IDE tool).

Answer (score 0):

Sharing pre-packaged service interfaces along with datacontracts isn't against SOA principles as long as consuming services are not expected to use it. This is exactly what enables potential clients to speed-up development against an existing 3rd-party service, or begin development against one which is yet to be built.  Providing interfaces/datacontracts in code format will be less ambiguous than describing these things via documentation only (of course they may not be useful if the client is using a different programming language).

However, if some sort of pre-packaged implementation of the service interface is provided in the shared package, and this implementation is required to be used to successfully use the service, then this would be against SOA principles unless an implementation was written for all types of clients. Being pragmatic though, this can be a good idea so the clients can be more loosely coupled against things such as transport choice, service contract changes and service versioning.

I would recommend using the ChannelFactory (from a dotnet client of course) whether consuming the services via a shared pre-packaged interfaces/datacontracts project or dll, or generating your own proxy (via 'Add Service Reference' or 'svcutil.exe').  This will allow you to code against the service interface and therefore your client will be much more friendly to using concepts such as dependency injection for stubbing, testing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods of generating a proxy are valid, it depends on how much control you wish to have over the proxy, and if you own both sides of the code. A third option also exists, you can hand craft your own proxy. Let me explain further:

In SOA we pass messages, this is a different paradigm to passing pointers to objects on a heap/stack which is the norm in OO world.

Thus in SOA, the contract (what you can do) and the message (the state to act upon) are important and need to be shared with the consumers of the service so they can all agree on the contract or "rules of engagement" here we have the most basic form of SOA.

Enter WS-* a set of specifications for adding more functionality to our service call (distributed transactions, security etc...) but if we do this we all need to agree on the rules and the flavor of the type of interaction we intend to use, so the service and its clients need to agree exactly on how this is to occur so it to needs to be shared.

The combination of the contract definitions and WS-* specifications is called a WSDL and this typically is what get shared between clients and services, this is in line with the SOA tenants that we share schema and contract, not class, and that Compatibility is based on policy (WS-*).

So if you use channel factory you generate the proxy based on the interface definition you have and the config you have set up on the fly, if you use add service reference you let the IDE generate a proxy class based on the WSDL of the service as it exists then.

If you hand craft the proxy, you have full control over how this happens and you can jump into the interception chain and do things on the client side to manipulate the call.

Depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The standards we have carefully considered and adopted at my company, are that we distribute service contracts is two ways.  As a shared assembly when delivered to teams within the company, and as a WSDL when providing to clients and other third parties.  It is a standard we discussed with Microsoft during a design / process review and they agreed was the correct approach.